# Configparser and string with %

Tags: python

Stupid question with (for sure) simple answer...

I am using configparser to read some strings from a file. When the string has the '%' symbol ($%& for example) it complains:

ConfigParser.InterpolationSyntaxError: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(', found: "%&'"

Anybody familiar with this?

Thanks!

Comment: i think you just need `%%` to escape it

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you don't want environment variable substitution, then use RawConfigParser, not ConfigParser.

Comment: This is because a `ConfigParser` by default does interpolation, which means you can refer to other parts of the file as `%(foo)`.

Comment: Feel free to add your love comments to http://bugs.python.org/issue26872 which is dealing with the change of behaviour between python 2 and 3 which was clearly not needed.

Comment: Upstream does **not** recommend to go this route for solving this issue. Instead, they recommend what @ChristopheWeis describes in his answer further below.

Comment: Good point! I updated coverage.py to avoid RawConfigParser now.  Thanks for the info.  https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/commit/f0f4761a459e1601c5b0c1043db5895e31c66e80

Answer (score 44):

Write **two** `%`:

```
V = ('%%', 'MHz', 'GHz')
```

result:

```
('%', 'MHz', 'GHz')
```

Comment: It helps when I wanted to use in circusd

Answer (score 42):

By default, ConfigParser has [interpolation of values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#interpolation-of-values) enabled. That means that you can use variables inside your properties files.

Since Python 3.2, you can disable interpolation in the constructor:

```
configParser = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=None)
```

If you don't want to disable interpolation, you must escape the *%* sign by putting two consecutive `%%` in the properties file as shown in the [example of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.BasicInterpolation).

Note that `RawConfigParser` is a legacy variant. From the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#rawconfigparser-objects):

> Consider using ConfigParser instead which checks types of the values
> to be stored internally. If you don’t want interpolation, you can use
> ConfigParser(interpolation=None).

Comment: This is great - needed to change only one line  in code !