# Python 3.4 Logging Configuration

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I am trying to convert my current projects from python 2.7 to 3.5. One of the first tasks is configuration of logging. I use a configuration file for flexibility and the date is part of the file name.
Below is the code for setting up the file handler that works fine in 2.7

```
[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
# Only one log per day will be created. All messages will be appended to it.
args=("D:\\Logs\\PyLogs\\" + time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")+'.log', 'a')
```

In 3.5 the following error occurs:

> configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(', found: '%Y%m%d%H%M%S")+\'.log\', \'a\')'

Has anyone experience with this? Is there a better way to format the date within the configuration file?

Comment: I'm surprised this worked at all in 2.7. Why not use a [`TimedRotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) though? `class=TimedRotatingFileHandler`, with `when='D'`.

Comment: I didn't use a TimeRotatingFileHandler, because it didn't do what I wanted, but thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

similar subject as this post:
[Configparser and string with %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340366/configparser-and-string-with)

I think you may need the substitution for %

Comment: I looked at that before and it didn't offer any help

Comment: Doubling the `%` did not fix it?

Comment: Actually it did fix it.
I had not tried it because I assumed that it would simply shift the problem from the configparser to time.strftime.