# Python: configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: '$' must be followed by '$' or '{', found: '$!'

Tags: python, special-characters, configparser

I have `psw: Test123$!` string in my configs.ini and tryin to read it with the following code will result in `configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: '$' must be followed by '$' or '{', found: '$!'` error:

```
configs = configparser.RawConfigParser()
configs._interpolation = configparser.ExtendedInterpolation()
configs.read(configs_path)

print(configs.get('app', 'psw', fallback=''))
```

I've seen other similar posts but all of them was referring to `%` as special character, not `$`! I tried escaping it inserting a double symbol (`psw: Test123$$!`) as suggested for the `%` symbol, but it didn't work. I can't find any reference to dollar symbol in the docs unless if it is followed by an open graph symbol (`${`)...so how to obtain a string containing a dollar symbol from an `.ini` file with `configparser`?

Comment: You explicitly added [an interpolation handler that treats `$` specially](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ExtendedInterpolation). If you plan on using that, your config file needs to use `$$` to specify a literal dollar sign.

Comment: Or see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62592195/6622587

Comment: The `_interpolation` attribute is undocumented; use `configs = RawConfigParser(interpolation=ExtendedInterpolation())` instead.